# Their product is a cubic of a rational number $x$ minus $x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

It is given the integer $6$. Analyze it into two parts such that their product is a cubic of a rational number $x$ minus $x$.

$$$$

Let $y$ be the one factor.

The other one is $6-y$.

We have that $$y \cdot (6-y)=x^3-x$$

How can we go on to find $x$ and $y$ ???

Comment: Typo? $x$ minus $x$?

Comment: @draks... I mean: Their product is a cubic of a rational number $x$ , minus $x$ $$\Rightarrow \text{ product }=x^3-x, x \in \mathbb{Q}$$

Comment: Is zero a valid solution for $x$ and $y$, i.e.$$0.(6-0)=0^3-0$$

Comment: @Mufasa I don't know, but I don't think so...

Comment: This corresponds to the elliptic curve in "standard form" $Y^2 = X^3 - X + 9$, where $Y = y-3$ and $X = -x$.  Yes, $(x=0,y=0)$ or $(X=0,Y=3)$ is a solution, as is $(x=0,y=6)$ ($X=0,Y=-3$).

Comment: Also $[X = -1, Y = \pm 3], [X = 1, Y = \pm 3], [X = 9, Y = \pm 27], [X = 35, Y = \pm 207], [X = 37, Y = \pm 225]$

Comment: @RobertIsrael How do we know that we have to take $$Y=y-3 \text{ and } X=-x$$ ??? Is there a general rule or something???

Comment: @user159870: Just completing the square in $y$, and then changing signs so we get $X^3$ instead of $-x^3$.

Comment: These integer solutions then generate rational solutions as in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCurve.html
e.g. $(-56/25, \pm 3/125)$, $(-17/9,  \pm 55/27)$, $(1/36, \pm 647/216)$ ...

Comment: 1121041
${x^3-x}=y(6-y)$
$(x-1)x(x+1)$
Since the OP specified rational numbers, $x=\frac{A}{B}$ and $y=\frac{C}{D}$.
So, ${\left(\frac{A}{B}-1\right)·\frac{A}{B}·\left(\frac{A}{B}+1\right)}={\frac{C}{D}·\left(6-\frac{C}{D}\right)}$.
${\frac{A-B}{B}·\frac{A}{B}·\frac{A+B}{B}}={\frac{C}{D}·\frac{6D-C}{D}}$.
${D^2A·(A-B)·(A+B)}={B^3C·(6D-C)}$

Comment: The rational solutions ($[X, \pm Y]$) where $X$ has numerator and denominator less than $1000$ in absolute value are
[-56/25, 3/125], [-17/9, 55/27], [-675/361, 14277/6859], [-1, 3], [0, 3], [1/36, 647/216], [1, 3], [19/9, 109/27], [621/289, 20121/4913], [664/169, 17811/2197], [785/196, 22833/2744], [65/16, 543/64], [9, 27], [35, 207], [37, 225]

Comment: Do we use the following: The genus of the elliptic curve $$Y^2=X^3-X+9$$ which is non-Singular, is $$g(C)=\frac{(3-1)(3-2)}{2}=1$$ so the curve has either none root or infinitely many roots ??? @RobertIsrael Do we have to find the elements of the abelian group $E(\mathbb{Q})$ ??? If yes, how can we do that??? How did you find these points???

Comment: @RobertIsrael Do we have to find the elements of the torsion abelian group $E(\mathbb{Q})_{\text{torsion}}$ ???